# Sharing BIP32 extended master public key

Tags: transactions, bip32-hd-wallets

I have `User A` who generates `BIP32` `Master Public and Private Keys`. They share the `Master Public Key` with `User B`.

Using the `Master Public Key` `User B` generates `Address of A` and sends bitcoins from `Address of B` to `Address of A`.

Will the transaction be received in wallet of `User A`, if `User A` knows the index used by `User B`?

The main idea is that `User A` don't want to share its receiving address with `User B`. Instead of that `User A` must find out itself from the `Master Public Key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would achieve the expected result, as both User A and User B can derive every possible address from that Master Public Key. It would effectively be the same as User B running a watch-only wallet with that MPK; they have to be able to see all the addresses:)